# Make a previously unknown number of parallel operations. In VHDL

Tags: parallel-processing, vhdl

Im working on a project for which I need to make calculations with vectors (orthogonalizing a matrix using gram schmidt method). The length of this vectors is unknown now, the program must be able to adapt to different lengths. One of such calculations is calculating a new vector (C) which is the result of adding A and B. Each element of the vectors is a number in fixed-point.

I want C(i)=A(i)+B(i). For all the elements of the vector (for i=0 to N, where N is the vector length).

I can find 2 solutions for this but both present some problems:

1- I can declare in the entity, vectors whose length changes according to a generic and then just create a for loop which goes through all the vector.

```
for I in 0 to N loop
    C(I)<=A(I)+B(I);
end loop;
```

The problem with this solution is that the execution would be sequential, and therefore slow. Im not completly sure about this and I dont know how to check it but I guess that the compiler is not smart enough to notice that it can be processed in parallel. In this application speed is a key factor.

2- I can declare vectors which are as long as the maximum possible length for the actual data and fill them with zeroes. Then I could just assign:

```
C(0)<=A(0)+B(0);
C(1)<=A(1)+B(1);
C(2)<=A(2)+B(2);
...
C(Nmax)<=A(Nmax)+B(Nmax);
```

This is not an elegant solution and in this application N can be between 3 and 300 therefore it could be a complete waste and tedious to program.

3- I want to find a third solution which could be able to create a number (asigned by the generic) of combinational calculations following a template such as C(i)=A(i)+B(i). Is there any solution like this? It is actually creating a loop which would not be executed sequentially but instead all at the same time.

I know that similar stuff can be done using CUDA but this project is actually a comparison between GPUs and FPGAs, so changing the platform is not a suitable solution either.

Thank you in advance

Edit: I have tought of another unsatisfactory solution but I want to share it in case it is helpful for somebody else checking this in the future. Given that A and B have the same length, you can write them in a 1-D format, that is: A(normal)=[1001,1100,0011], A(1-D)=100111000011. The same would be done with B.

If you know before hand that the sum of any two possible numbers can be expressed with the same amount of bits, there will be no problems. So with 4 unsigned bits you should make sure that in any possible case the numbers in A or B are !>0111 (not higher than 0111). You could just write C(1-D)=A(1-D)+B(1-D) and then just asign C(0)=C(1-D)(3 downto 0), C(1)=C(1-D)(7 downto 4) etc.

If you cannot make sure that the numbers are not higher than 0111 (in the 4 bit case) it wont work.

Comment: Loops are unrolled in synthesis and for each iteration of the sequence of statements within which the loop variable is treated as a constant. It's completely parallel when any assignment targets have different indexed names (indexed by I here). That doesn't guarantee for large values of N, operations consuming specific resources or a greater complexity of the sequence of statements  in a loop you won't run out of FPGA resources. There can also be restrictions on N based on a the target arrays elements being large enough to require RAM and N not fitting the word width. Show declarations.

Comment: Your solution 3 sounds like a generate loop.

Comment: I understand then that this:  for I in 0 to 3 loop
    C(I)<=A(I)+B(I);
end loop; is as fast as C(0)<=A(0)+B(0); C(1)<=A(1)+B(1); C(2)<=A(2)+B(2); C(3)<=A(3)+B(3);? That would be really helpful, thanks a lot, I will definitely check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the length attribute to create a loop depending on the size of your vector.

https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html

As mentioned in the comment to the question the loop should be unrolled as long as it is not synchronized to the clock.